# VS code ,py file No such file or directory Error

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

`PS C:\Users\User\Desktop\python\sqlite> python prac.py C:\Users\User\anaconda3\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\python\sqlite\prac.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

When I try to run VS code and command prompt, I always have this kind of error. However, when I ran `import os` and checked the file through Jupyter, Jupyter could find prac.py which I wanted to run. And I tried diverse solutions but I still have this problem.

I am learning coding less than 1 month, and I'm not good at english because I'm a foreigner. I want you to tell me the solution as detailed and easy as possible..!

Comment: When you use Jupyter are you also in `C:\Users\User\Desktop\python\sqlite`?

Comment: yes,, I always use same directory

Comment: Does `C:\Users\User\Desktop\python\sqlite\prac.py` exists?

Comment: Wow, I found it.. 'prac.py' is wrong name, but 'prac' is right one. Thank you!